# Ajax. Sending data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good day, I'm trying to use Ajax in my web application. But I have a little problem with it. I try to control a form if some username has already been registered or not. But my JavaScript seem does not send $_POST value to PHP. And responses that user in not defined on the line where I have $_POST['user'].

Here what I have.

PHP:

```
<?php
$opt = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
$dsn ='mysql:dbname=someone;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8';
$user='someone';
$pswd='aaa';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pswd, $opt);
$query="SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE  username = :username";   
        $query_p=array(':username' => $_POST['user']); 

        try 
        { 
            $statment = $dbh->prepare($query); 
            $result = $statment->execute($query_p); 
        }catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo "Can't run query: " . $e->getMessage();        
     } 
        $row = $statment->fetch();
        if($row){           
        return 0;
        }else {
        return 1;
        }
?>
```

So it opens a connection to database and runs a query

JavaScript:

```
function checkUser(e){
    var state1 = document.getElementById("alert_text");
    var u = document.getElementById("user").value;
    if(u != ""){

        state1.innerHTML = 'processing...';
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open("POST", "validation.php", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    var result=request.responseText;
alert(result);
   if(result==1){
        state1.innerHTML="OK";
    }else{
        state1.innerHTML="Alredy exists!";
    }
    }
  };
        request.send(u);
        var slova = request.responseText;
        }
}
document.getElementById("user").addEventListener("blur",checkUser,false );
```

So technically it is ajax.

HTML:

```
<form id="check"  name="signUp" method="post">
 <p class="alert_text"></p>
   <label for="user">Username:</label><br />

   <input id="user" name="user"  type="text" ><br />

</form>
```

I don't really see what's the problem...

Comment: use "POST" in your ajax call instead of "GET".

Comment: @steady_daddy php still don't know what is user

Comment: You dont have an `alert_text` id in your form

Comment: why is this commented out? `//$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pswd, $opt);` given the other answers.

Comment: Seems like you're just passing the value but not the key=>value pair. See @jeroen's answer below.

Comment: [See this comment also...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014073/ajax-sending-data-to-php-file#comment57755560_35014218) that I left under Jeroen's answer. You have quite a few bugs.

Comment: *Yoohoo!* OP, where are (*you?*) we with this question? ;-) Answers, comments but nothing to say what's firing or not. I have now moved on. Good luck with that.

Comment: I just gone to have some cofee, sorry :). Now I'm back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the edited question: You are not sending any key-value pairs to the server, just a single value.

You need to change:

```
var u = document.getElementById("user").value;
```

to:

```
var u = 'user=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("user").value);
```

And then later on the pair will be sent correctly:

```
request.send(u);    // sends a single key-value pair
```

Note that I have just added the `encodeURIComponent` function to make sure the value gets encoded correctly.

Comment: and not sure if OP did uncomment out `//$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pswd, $opt);` - If not, it's also not connecting.

Comment: `document.getElementById("alert_text")` and they're using `<p class="alert_text"></p>`, the operative word here being `class` so that never happens. A lot of bugs in there ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmmmm, I think I'll just focus on the `JavaScript seem does not send $_POST value to PHP` part. The OP can fix the others as they appear.

Comment: We haven't heard from the OP since, so it's hard to say what's firing or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fixed it all and moved on to another project?

Comment: Probably, or he's gone out to get us all coffee and a danish for all our hard work. ;-)

Comment: @jeroen I figured out that request is sent to validation.php but it still can't identify it even if I edit code as you said.

Comment: @jeroen now I've changed to `var u = 'user=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("user").value);` But now I have no response from php.

Comment: What do you see in your `alert(result);` line? Does anything come back? Or in the developer tools Network request, what's the response from your PHP script?

Comment: @MattAndrews `result` is empty

Comment: What happens if you replace `return 1` and `return 0` with `echo '1'` and `echo '0'`? Been a while since I did any PHP but it might be that if your script doesn't echo anything back, the JavaScript doesn't see anything.

Comment: @MattAndrews FINALLY! Thank you! It works now! I've changed it to echo. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You're not passing the username into the PHP script. Your PHP is looking for a POST variable, `$_POST['user']` – in your JavaScript you make a GET request, so the PHP script has nothing to look up.

Comment: yes, you are right. I do it with POST I just tried it with GET. But it either not working with POST

Comment: It sounds like the `user` variable isn't making it through to your PHP script. If you look in your browser developer tools in the Network tab, you should see a request to `validation.php` – what parameters are being sent? Is `user` there?

Comment: Form Data user:gusevvas so it sends something.